# reassign values in a list without looping

Tags: r

```
test <- list(a = list("first"= 1, "second" = 2), 
         b = list("first" = 3, "second" = 4))
```

In the list above, I would like to reassign the "first" elements to equal, let's say, five. This for loop works:

```
for(temp in c("a", "b")) {
  test[[temp]]$first <- 5
}
```

Is there a way to do the same using a vectorized operation (lapply, etc)? The following extracts the values, but I can't get them reassigned:

```
lapply(test, "[[", "first")
```

Comment: Agreed. Bad usage on my part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
test <- lapply(test, function(x) {x$first <- 5; x})
```

Comment: you need to assign the function to test for it to work.  test  <- lapply(test, function(x) {x$first <- 5; x}) otherwise it just prints to the screen.

Comment: Correct, @user1945827. That's true for 99% of R functions, so I didn't include it in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a vectorised one-liner using `unlist` and `relist`:

```
relist((function(x) ifelse(grepl("first",names(x)),5,x))(unlist(test)),test)
$a
$a$first
[1] 5

$a$second
[1] 2


$b
$b$first
[1] 5

$b$second
[1] 4
```